# Why only 4 chars get sent to serial port via command-line

Tags: tty, serial-port, echo

I'm trying to communicate with NodeMCU (CP210x USB/UART) from command-line. However it does not respond to my commands. I have set the correct baudrate via `stty 9600 raw`.

```
echo "gpio.write(0,gpio.LOW)" >/dev/ttyUSB0
```

It works when some other program is using / listening on the `/dev/ttyUSB0` (`minicom`, `screen` or even `cat /dev/ttyUSB0`).

When no other program is using the tty, it does not work. I have confirmed the stty settings are the same all the time.

From the error messages from NodeMCU I confirmed that it receives only first 4 characters of my command (when no other prog is using the port), so as a workaround I have made this work:

```
echo -n "gpio" >/dev/ttyUSB0
echo -n ".wri" >/dev/ttyUSB0
echo -n "te(0" >/dev/ttyUSB0
echo -n ",gpi" >/dev/ttyUSB0
echo -n "o.LO" >/dev/ttyUSB0
echo    "W)"   >/dev/ttyUSB0
```

Can someone explain me what is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev do you think that having `cat /dev/ttyUSB0` in 2nd window changes the flow control somehow? Also the `stty -a` shows the same settings in both cases, so the flow control is set the same.

Comment: Is the other end expecting hardware or software [flow control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_control_%28data%29#Transmit_flow_control)?

Comment: When the port is opened by a process, its DTR signal is asserted. It's possible the signal goes down before the buffer has been completely written (`echo` has closed the port but there's still data in the buffer). Try `(echo "gpio.write(0,gpio.LOW)"; sleep 1) >/dev/ttyUSB0`

Comment: @wurtel Interesting idea, however it doesn't work... maybe DTR is asserted only when device is opened for input? Do you know of any way how to assert DTR from command-line?

Comment: input or output shouldn't make any difference in my experience, although as this is a USB device the driver may not have implemented the normal serial IO behaviour correctly.